# FIO processes go from aiospn to 100% CPU

Tags: freebsd, fio

I'm using FreeBSD 12.2 and FIO 3.24. The ioengine parameter is posixaio. Testing NVMe drives. During the initial part of our testing, we hit the unit under test with a QD of 32 and numjobs of 4 for 3 hours (randomwrite with a mix of blocksizes . Usually about 2/3rds of the way through, I notice the 4 processes (one by one) go from state aiospn usually using 5-10% CPU to state CPUnnn at 100 %CPU. vfs.aio values below.

The question is who is the guilty party? FreeBSD vs FIO?  I'm taking a guess that someone isn't handling a dropped I/O request well.

```
vfs.aio.max_buf_aio: 8192
vfs.aio.max_aio_queue_per_proc: 65536
vfs.aio.max_aio_per_proc: 8192
vfs.aio.aiod_lifetime: 30000
vfs.aio.num_unmapped_aio: 0
vfs.aio.num_buf_aio: 0
vfs.aio.num_queue_count: 0
vfs.aio.max_aio_queue: 65536
vfs.aio.target_aio_procs: 4
vfs.aio.num_aio_procs: 4
vfs.aio.max_aio_procs: 32
vfs.aio.unsafe_warningcnt: 1
vfs.aio.enable_unsafe: 0
```

Comment: Hard to say. How good is FreeBSD's posix AIO (Linux's POSIX AIO is famously bad)? I hear you have to have a kernel module or somesuch on FreeBSD which makes it good but I don't know much about the platform... [fio is happy to resubmit I/O when `EAGAIN` is returned while queuing posixaio](https://github.com/axboe/fio/blob/fio-3.25/engines/posixaio.c#L177) is returned so who can tell? You'd need a profile to tell you were all the time is going.